# How can I avoid the player from moving through walls?

Tags: unity-game-engine

The problem is that the objects that make the space station are too many over 1000 objects. So it's hard to go one by one and add a collider to it.

The player have a Rigodbody and I'm using it to detect when entering a door and collide with the door collider and then open the door/s .

I marked with red circle one part of the space station for example that don't have any collider on it. So the player can move through it.

This is the screenshot also of the player inspector settings :

[image: Player]

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question is that you don't want the player to pass through the walls. So then when you import an FBX there are import options with a checkbox asking if you want to generate colliders. Just check that off and hit apply.

Answer (score 1):

If you only add colliders to walls you'll still very likely hit into the wall when you stand too close. Read the doc about [navmesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html), it bakes walkable space and autogenerates margin for non-walkable objects. It's thorough enough.

Also check Youtube channels (there are a lot).